# RabbitMQ multithreaded basicPublish best practice

Tags: rabbitmq

I have been reading up on how to use RabbitMQ's channels correctly in a multithreaded environment, and I think I've got the consuming side licked (one channel per consumer). However, what should I do about publishing -- this is a bit unclear to me at the moment?

In a situation where I've got various threads coming into a "send" method, should I:

1. Create and discard a channel per message or
2. Create a single channel for publishing and synchronize so that multiple threads don't step on each other?

Comment: why don't you synchronize your code block which publishes the message to the queue?

Comment: That is essentially (2). Which is what I ended up doing.